# Как с помощью python достать нужную часть текста из txt файла

Tags: python, python-3.x, lua, txt

Есть lua файл от аддона TradeSkillMaster, который содержит в себе информацию о количестве вещей в гильдейском банке, сумке и аукционе. Хотя python может прочитать содержимое lua файла, я все равно поменял формат на txt.

В данном примере 6 строк разных вещей, но их может быть любое количество от 0 до 100.
Мне нужно собирать эти данные, в независимости от количества строк, для дальнейшей обработки.

```
["c@Altcoin - Frostmourne@internalData@auctionMessages"] = {
},
["f@Alliance - Thrall@internalData@mailDisenchantablesChar"] = "",
["g@ @coreOptions@auctionSaleSound"] = "TSM_NO_SOUND",
["f@Alliance - Kel'Thuzad@internalData@guildVaults"] = {
    ["Guild Name"] = {
        ["i:9304"] = 3,
        ["i:171412::+15"] = 8,
        ["i:172329::+15"] = 5,
        ["i:171416::+15"] = 8,
        ["i:12958"] = 1,
        ["i:171415::+15"] = 8,
    },
},
["f@Alliance - Moon Guard@internalData@mats"] = {
},
["c@Abobus - Dalaran@internalData@craftingCooldowns"] = {
},
["c@Aboba - Area 52@internalData@craftingCooldowns"] = {
},
["f@Alliance - Kel'Thuzad@internalData@characterGuilds"] = {
    ["Charecter"] = "Guild Name",
},
```

Как получить текст между фигурными скобками ["Guild Name"] = { } с помощью python? Возможно ли это?

Я смог только прочитать данный файл, но что делать дальше не знаю.

```
auction_data = open('TradeSkillMaster.txt','r')
print(auction_data.read())
```

Comment: Что значит "вычленить все элементы"? Если просто получить текст между фигурными скобками, то можно регуляркой.

Comment: Все верно. Мне нужно получить текст между фигурными скобками

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import re

with open(r'c:\test\TradeSkillMaster.txt', 'r') as auction_data:
    txt = re.search(r'\["Guild Name"\] = {([^}]*)}', auction_data.read())
if txt:
    print(txt.group(1))
else:
    print('Ничего не найдено :(')
```

```
        ["i:9304"] = 3,
        ["i:171412::+15"] = 8,
        ["i:172329::+15"] = 5,
        ["i:171416::+15"] = 8,
        ["i:12958"] = 1,
        ["i:171415::+15"] = 8,
```